# Not showing the future builder of hot products which is placed after the department future builder in column

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show two future builders with gridview in the column widget, but it is showing me one future builder of the department and not showing the other future builder when scrolling it. how to show the future builder of hot product? it will be helpful for me

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:apipractice/Models/Category_model.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Models/Department_model.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Models/HotProduct_model.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Screens/Department.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Screens/cart.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Screens/categorry.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Screens/products.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Screens/selected_Category.dart';
import 'package:apipractice/Screens/subCategory.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<HotProductModel> getHotProducts() async {
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return HotProductModel.fromJson(data[0]);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }

  List images = [
    "assets/Image1.jpeg",
    "assets/Image2.jpeg",
    "assets/Image3.jpeg",
    "assets/Image4.jpeg",
    "assets/Image5.jpeg",
    "assets/Image6.jpeg",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/user.png")),
                  radius: 25,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  "Username",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Text("abcuser@gmail.com"),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.note),
              title: const Text('Show Product'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Products()),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.note),
              title: const Text('Show Category'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Categorry()),
                );
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.note),
              title: const Text('Department'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Department()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 24, 119, 197),
        title: Text("Dubai Super Store"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: ((context) => Cart()),
                  ),
                );
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 35,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                  prefixIconColor: Colors.blue,
                  labelText: "Search Product",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Note: Free Delivery Above Rs.2000",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.red.shade700,
                  fontSize: 17),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                itemCount: images.length,
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  height: 400,
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  autoPlay: true,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index, realindex) {
                  final urlImages = images[index];

                  return buildImage(urlImages, index);
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Categorry()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Image(
                          height: 70,
                          width: 70,
                          image: AssetImage("assets/Categories.jpeg"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Categories")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SubCategory()),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Image(
                            height: 70,
                            width: 70,
                            image: AssetImage("assets/SubCategory.jpeg")),
                      ),
                      Text("Sub Category")
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              "Department",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 113, 192)),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<DepartmentModel>(
              future: getDepartment(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return GridView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.sKUDepartmentDetail!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            var fetchid =
                                "${snapshot.data!.sKUDepartmentDetail![index].sKUDeptId}";
                            fetchCategory = fetchid;
                            setState(() {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => SelectedCategory()),
                              );
                            });
                          },
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            elevation: 10.0,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Stack(children: [
                                    CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl: snapshot
                                          .data!
                                          .sKUDepartmentDetail![index]
                                          .imageUrl1!,
                                      height: 150,
                                      width: 200,
                                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
                                        return Image(
                                            image: AssetImage(
                                                "assets/placeholder.jpg"));
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  snapshot
                                      .data!.sKUDepartmentDetail![index].name!,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            // SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              "Hot Product",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<HotProductModel>(
                future: getHotProducts(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.productDetail!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  blurRadius: 3,
                                  offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: snapshot.data!.productDetail![index]
                                      .sKUImageURL1!,
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
                                    return Image(
                                        image: AssetImage(
                                            "assets/placeholder.jpg"));
                                  },
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                    "${snapshot.data!.productDetail![index].sKUName!}"),
                                Text(
                                  "Rs: ${snapshot.data!.productDetail![index].salePrice!}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Rs: ${snapshot.data!.productDetail![index].retailPrice!}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                      color: Colors.red),
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      var product = snapshot
                                          .data!.productDetail![index].sKUId;
                                      if (cartList.contains(product)) {
                                        print("already exist");
                                      } else {
                                        cartList.add({
                                          "Id": snapshot
                                              .data!.productDetail![index].sKUId
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Text("Add to Cart"))
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the output of the code

[![output image][1]][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved it is only not showing because of screen navigation bar now its fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).